# How to calculate the Sum of Column and show On FooterRow In Jqgrid in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Hii Guys!!
               I displayed data in jqgrid and enabled ' footerrow: true' in jqgrid Now as per my need i want to show the sum of particular column on footer Row...Plz guys Help me as I am using Jqgrid For first time ...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2820563/315935) for the answer and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A315935+footerrow) for more examples on the same subject which I answered before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to sum the values which are in the jqGrid, you can do that in JavaScript (preferably in `gridComplete` event):

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid({
    ...
    footerrow: true,
    gridComplete: function() {
        var $grid = $('#gridId');
        var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', '<Your column name>', false, 'sum');
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'Your column name>: colSum });
    }
});
```

If you need to calculate the sum on the server side, then you must enable `userDataOnFooter` option first:

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid({
    ...
    footerrow : true,
    userDataOnFooter : true
});
```

And then include the sum in your server response. For exmple in case of JSON it should look like this:

```
{
    total: x,
    page: y,
    records: z,
    rows : [
        ...
    ],
    userdata: { <Your column name>: <sum counted on server side> }
}
```

You can also take a look at live example available on [jqGrid Demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page (you should choose "New in Version 3.5" and then "Summary Footer Row").

Comment: Here is the code that i added but its not working Sir  rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#UsersGridPager',
                sortname: 'UserID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                autowidth: true,
                toppager: true,
                footerrow: true, 
                gridComplete: function() {
        var $grid = $('#UsersGrid');
        var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', '<Balance>', false, 'sum');
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'Balance>: colSum' });
    }

Comment: @vikas I believe I got you confused with the '<' and '>' brackets, your code should be more like this: gridComplete: function() { var $grid = $('#UsersGrid'); var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Balance', false, 'sum'); $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Balance: colSum }); }

Comment: How cam i use on click function on total record?