# Display SUM of each Column , jqGRID

Tags: php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am using jqGrid and displaying my data in grid
 I have 5 columns. I want to calculate SUM of each column and display the sum at the end of the column , probably in the footer.![In the below image, the TOTAL is displayed only for Amount col, I want it to be displayed for all the columns at the end of the column [Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCKWi.png)

Comment: Did you got the output by trying my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using **LoadComplete - function**

To show sum of **Amount** column as **Total** in the footer of the grid, then you should enable *footerrow* and you should use *loadComplete* function like below,

```
footerrow: true,
loadComplete: function () {
       var sumOfPrice = jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('getCol','Amount',false,'sum');           
       jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Date: 'Total:', Amount: sumOfPrice });                     
}
```

For more info regrading loadComplete function, have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481751/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-column-and-show-on-footerrow-in-jqgrid-in-asp-net).

Comment: jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Date: 'Total:', Amount: sumOfPrice });

In the above line , cant we make the  colName (Ex: Date and AMmount ) to be dynamic, like taking these from an array ??

Comment: I used gridComplete instead of loadComplete.. referred from other stackoverflow link