# Accessing Key from JSON Encoded Response Using CakePHP in JQGrid Column Summary

Tags: php, jquery, json, cakephp, jqgrid

I am sending json encoded results from my controller to my view and displaying data in jqgrid. The data is displaying fine. However, I added two integers to the response I am returning and I want to display them in the grid in one of the column's summary. This is what it looks like in the controller:

```
    $response->TotalNum = $total_items;
    $response->PercentNum = $percent_items;
    return json_encode($response);
```

How do I access those values in my grid? I would like to append them to the summary. Sort of like this, though I know this won't work:

```
{name:'itemcounts',index:'itemcounts', width: 50, sorttype:'int',summaryType:'sum', summaryTpl: 'Total<br>Count: {0}<br>Total Items: **$response['TotalNum']** (**$response['PercentNum']**%)', formatter:'number',formatoptions:{decimalPlaces: 0}},
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to display summary row and fill it with the data prepared on the server is the usage of additional `userdata` property in the server response (its values mast be an object with properties  defined as the column names) and options `footerrow: true` and `userDataOnFooter`. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820563/315935) provides the corresponding example. If you prefer calculate the values for the footer row *on the client side* (which can be slowly) then you can calculate the summary using `getCol` and then call `footerData` explicitly inside of `loadComplete` callback. By the way the setting `summaryType:'sum'` will be used in case of groping of data (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622718/315935) for example).